# Aproveite a Copa com moderação!

Tags: debate, moderação

Vocês são parte de um dos sites mais bem sucedidos nesses anos de Stack Exchange. Um site que cresce constantemente, que fica cada vez mais movimentado e com uma comunidade cada vez mais diversa.

Contar com a participação de pessoas com diferentes experiências é o que torna o site cada vez melhor, aglomerando mais e mais conhecimento. Por outro lado, ter mais pessoas significa contar com mais pontos de vistas e opiniões sobre o site, sendo essencial que todos esses grupos sejam representados e levados em conta no gerenciamento da comunidade.

Por mais sensacional que eu seja <sup>[carece de fontes]</sup>, não faz mais sentido manter apenas um par de olhos em tudo que acontece no site. E é aí que entram nossos moderadores!

O SOPT enfrenta diversos desafios enquanto cresce. Alguns normais, outros bastante específicos da nossa comunidade e não há nada mais justo que garantir que nossos problemas sejam tratados por pessoas de dentro da própria comunidade.

Eventualmente o site vai contar com moderadores eleitos pela própria comunidade, mas esse não é o caso dessa vez. Nossos novos moderadores foram escolhidos pela equipe do Stack Exchange e temos plena confiança de que farão um excelente trabalho.

## E a moderação vai para...

[image: bfavaretto] [image: utluiz]

Boas-vindas aos dois, que aceitaram voluntariar seu tempo para ajudar o SOPT a ser cada vez melhor. Ambos demonstraram empenho e dedicação ao site, e já fizeram bastante pela comunidade. Estamos muito felizes em poder contar com os dois e tenho certeza de que serão muito bem recebidos por todos.

## E a moderação não foi para...

Certamente existem mais usuários capazes de moderar o site, e que merecem o reconhecimento da comunidade. A escolha dos nossos moderadores não é uma rejeição aos diversos outros usuários que dedicaram seu tempo para ajudar o site. Eventualmente teremos uma comunidade capaz de votar nos seus próprios moderadores, e todos poderão se candidatar.

## Então...

Sejam educados e compreensivos com os novos moderadores. Eles ainda estão aprendendo e se adaptando à nova função, voluntariamente e pelo nosso bem coletivo. Todos nós vamos aprender coisas novas com essa nova fase do SOPT!

Comment: Parabéns aos novos moderadores!

Comment: Dentre muitos vários, um par de craques com certeza! Como dizem los hermanos: *¡en hora buena!*

Comment: Finalmente! Parabéns aos novos ♦s, e que mantenham o legado vivo!

Comment: Parabéns e bom trabalho :)

Comment: Carece de fontes... Sensacional! Parabéns ao dois!

Comment: Gabe, o título desta pergunta foi legal na época, agora mesmo, acho que não faz muito sentido. Custei pra achar ela e adicionei uma tag relevante para facilitar.

Comment: @brasofilo Faz todo sentido

Answer (score 25):

Boa tarde, comunidade do Stack Overflow em Português! Este é meu primeiro "comunicado oficial" como moderador pré Copa 2014.

Como muitos aqui sabem, sou relativamente novo na cultura do SO, pois não participava ativamente de outras redes como StackOverflow, Programmers e cia. Também já cheguei a dizer que não tinha jeito para moderar (e ainda não sei se tenho).

Mas talvez essa tenha sido justamente a razão do meu apontamento, de modo a agregar valores num site que tem vida própria e é diferente em vários aspectos, do qual participo desde o seu primeiro dia de existência.

Para mim será uma nova experiência. Aceitei-a pelo desafio e pela possibilidade de colaborar com o crescimento de nossa comunidade, enquanto me for permitido.

**Espero fazer isso com transparência e dedicação!**

Fico à disposição de quem tiver alguma dúvida ou assunto relacionado à função (vocês podem me chamar lá no chat usando o arroba `@`).

Comment: Seja bem vindo. Grandes expectativas! :)

Comment: Como disse o @Filipe.Fonseca, grandes expectativas. Parabéns pela escolha, e que sua identidade contribua para agregar, somando-se com a expectativa da SE via Gabe, e especialmente da comunidade, pois as 3 coisas são relevantes para um bom trabalho. Sucesso.

Comment: @Bacco disse tudo :)

Comment: Parabéns utluiz, não existe escolha mais justa para moderador do que você que está sempre disposto a ajudar, testar novas idéias e ajudar o formular o que o Stack Overflow é!

Answer (score 20):

Obrigado pelas boas-vindas, pessoal!

Como muitos já sabem, eu estou sempre no site, no meta e (menos) no chat. E quando não posso estar presente, costumo ver o que aconteceu enquanto estive fora. Isso não significa que eu veja *tudo*! Então por favor me ajudem sinalizando as perguntas, respostas e comentários onde virem algum problema. Quando precisarem falar comigo, me chamem com `@bfavaretto` no chat, e eu apareço assim que possível.

Peço um pouco de paciência de vocês agora no começo. São muitas ferramentas novas para eu me familiarizar. Tem um monte de coisas para eu aprender, sobre as ferramentas e sobre moderação em geral.

O que eu (por enquanto) *acho* que vai acontecer é:

- Postarei menos respostas por dividir meu tempo com a moderação, mas pretendo continuar respondendo, porque é uma coisa que gosto muito de fazer.
- Como meu voto agora decide sozinho, vocês não me verão mais votando para fechar ou reabrir perguntas, exceto em casos excepcionais em que eu tenha certeza de estar fazendo a coisa certa (e se mesmo assim eu não estiver, reclamem!).
- Devo continuar avaliando edições sugeridas, gosto de fazer isso. Não sei bem se os moderadores têm poderes especiais nessa ferramenta. Se for mais um caso em que meu voto decide sozinho, devo pular muitas perguntas.

Isso sem falar no que eu ainda não sei... Só sei que estou bem feliz de poder contribuir mais ainda com o site e a comunidade!

Comment: "eu estou sempre no site, no meta e (menos) no chat." Gostei disso, e acho que o meta deve ser o canal e repositório oficial para qualquer coisa. Parabéns, dado seu histórico no SOpt e SO, acho que a escolha foi merecidíssima. Sucesso.

Comment: Boa sorte com os novos poderes e ferramentas @bfavaretto, tenho certeza que você fará um trabalho excelente.

Answer (score 15):

Parabéns aos dois. Acho que posso dizer que a comunidade tem confiança em ambos. Era o que faltava para o site. Esperamos todos que ajudem o site ser uma lugar melhor.

Podem contar comigo para o que for necessário.

Comment: Obrigado bigown! Com toda a sua atuação no site, nem tenho dúvidas de que continuará colaborando bastante.

Comment: É isso aí bigown! Metade do que eu sei sobre o SO aprendi com você e a outra metade é que falta eu aprender. Então continue com o excelente trabalho!

Answer (score 10):

Tenho de participar também e dar os meus parabéns aos dois! Parabéns ao Gabe também por ter escolhido dois membros que ganharam e merecem o respeito e apoio da comunidade!

Contem connosco!

Comment: Eu falei que esse dia ia chegar, né? :D

Answer (score 7):

**Parabéns aos novos moderadores!** Creio que a escolha foi sensata, ambos são usuários ativos (no bom sentido kk) e que contribuem para o crescimento e ordem da comunidade. Não conheço bem quais são os privilégios da moderação, mas reconheço a confiança no bfavaretto e no utluiz (que não são do PT kkk, brincadeira). Boa moderação e contem conosco!

Comment: Um aparte, redhat!!! :D