# Nossos diamantes não brilham como os de lá

Tags: bug, design

Ontem ganhamos [novos diamantes](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1452/aproveite-a-copa-com-moderacao), no entando estava a os apreciar e notei que sub determinadas circustâncias eles não brilham da forma como eu esperava. A diferença só é notável em comentários e aqui no meta.

O ponto é que quando alguém comenta, o seu nome é um link para seu perfil. Se a pessoa for honrada com um diamante, então clicar nele **também vai ao perfil**. Olhando o html da página fica claro que o `<span>` está dentro do `<a>`. Essa é a diferença entre como aparece em qualquer outro lugar e como aparece nos comentários. (Deveria ser unificado não? O ♦ ser fora do link.)

Mas o problema todo é que no visual do SOPT no meta, links clicados e links não clicados tem diferença significativa de cor, diferente do metaSO. Um nome de usuário cujo perfil não vi é vermelho. Os que vi é azul. O problema todo é que o diamante não muda de cor junto com o link. Sua cor é fixa:

```
.mod-flair {
    margin-left: 3px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #6c0000;
    font-size: 15px;
}
```

Está dentro do link, mas não se comporta como um link. É clicável, mas não responde como o esperado de coisas clicáveis. Eu sou o único incomodado com isso?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

<sub><sub>Isso é tão minor que acho que vai terminar com um bydesign mesmo. Mas meus olhos doem e não pude ignorar.</sub></sub>

Comment: +1 por `estava a os apreciar`