# Tradução faltando na listagem dos moderadores

Tags: bug, status-pronto, internacionalização

Na página de usuários, aba "moderadores", a data de nomeação dos mesmos ainda está em inglês:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Reparei nisso porque a data está no padrão americano, o que me levou a pensar "por que eles ainda não ganharam a medalha [Policial](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/85/constable)?" - até me dar conta que [eles começaram dia 3 de junho](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1452/aproveite-a-copa-com-modera%C3%A7%C3%A3o), não 6 de março... :P

Tradução sugerida:

> nomeado(a) d/m/yyyy

ou talvez:

> nomeação d/m/yyyy